# Python way to open a text file, select every nth value, and save to a text file.

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file that contains 57,600,000 million lines of values. These values are in a single column in the text file. They represent a 150(column) x 160(row) matrix repeated 2400 times. I wish to complete 2 different operations, each with 3 objectives.

Operation 1 (column)

1. Open the text file
2. Select every nth data point
3. Save the selected values to another text or .csv file

Operation 2 (row)

1. Open the text file
2. Select a range of values (150) starting every nth line
3. Save the selected values to another text or .csv file

The point of this is to print a matrix column and then a row. I am a novice python user and am using spyder to run other scripts. If you would be kind enough to write a script for me, please be descriptive on what I would need to replace to get the desired results. I have looked through other similar postings but cannot find a thread that is similar enough that I could edit to my needs, with my limited knowledge.

Thank you very much for looking and any assistance you can give.

Comment: ["write a script for me"](http://www.freelancer.com/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Files in Python are iterators, meaning they can be looped over, or have iteration operations applied to them.

To get every 5th line, for example, would be:

```
import itertools

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    fifthlines = itertools.islice(f, 0, None, 5)
    for line in fifthlines:
        # do something with line
```

You can use `islice()` to skip lines too; here we skip 10 lines, then read 10:

```
for line in itertools.islice(f, 10, 20):
    # do something with this 10th line
```

You can swallow a series; because skipping, then reading 0 lines raises a `StopIteration` signal, we swallow that by using `next()` and passing in a default value to be returned instead:

```
next(itertools.islice(f, 42, 42), None)  # skip 42 lines, don't read more
```

With the [`itertools` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), and a quick scan through the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) you can figure out the rest of the script easily enough.

Comment: to skip 10 lines wouldn't that be `islice(f, 10, 20)`?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen yes; I think I wanted to demonstrate different operations. Reading this back I can see there are better ways of accomplishing the skipping anyway. I'll update this later on when I have some time.